# ASP.NET Razor View Hashes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this code here

```
@Html.ActionLink("Careers", "Index", "Contact")
```

I am looking to add a hash to it like so #careers

so the URL will be /Contact/Index#careers

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Nope, All I get is the link and then #Careers as text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the `Url` helper to compose the link:

```
<a href="@(Url.Action("Index", "Contact"))#carrers">your text</a>
```

this will create a link:

```
<a href="/Contact/Index#carrers">your text</a>
```